# Java GUi Being inconsistent

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Hi so I am trying to creat this menu for the game, and when I run the code it is very hit or miss. In the same computer with same screen same OS and everything the same, I might run the code ones and the menu is fine. and then I run it again and the pictures are missalighed or the just disappear and so on. I have tried changing the order of the contentPane.add but and I am out of ideas. What else could it be? Thanks

```
public static int type(){
      // Create a "clickable" image icon

    int i =0;
    Color c = new Color (0,0,0);
       ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("images/mike_main.png");
       JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
       ImageIcon icon1 = new ImageIcon("images/igal_main.png");
       JLabel label1 = new JLabel(icon1);
       JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();

       JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Choose your character!");
       JLabel mike_l = new JLabel("Mike");
       JLabel mike_info = new JLabel("<html>Speed: 10<br>Range: 7</html>");
       JLabel igal_l = new JLabel("Igal");
       JLabel igal_info = new JLabel("<html>Speed: 7<br>Range: 10</html>");


       label3.setBounds(600,100,2000,100);
       label3.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 56));
       label3.setForeground(Color.WHITE);


       contentPane.setOpaque(true);
       contentPane.setBackground(c);
       contentPane.setLayout(null);
       final JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Window");
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       frame.getContentPane().add(label);
       frame.setTitle("The Ultimate Game");
       frame.setExtendedState(frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
       frame.pack();
       frame.setVisible(true);
       label.setBounds(400,400,300,600);
       mike_l.setBounds(500,330,1000,100);
       mike_info.setBounds(750,500,1000,100);
       //label.setLocation(50, 50);
       label1.setBounds(1200,400,300,600);
       igal_l.setBounds(1300,330,1000,100);
       igal_info.setBounds(1550,500,1000,100);
       //label1.setLocation(250, 250);
       mike_l.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 26));
       mike_l.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
       mike_info.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 26));
       mike_info.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
       igal_l.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 26));
       igal_l.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
       igal_info.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 26));
       igal_info.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
       contentPane.add(label);
       contentPane.add(label1);
       contentPane.add(label3);
       contentPane.add(mike_l);
       contentPane.add(mike_info);
       contentPane.add(igal_l);
       contentPane.add(igal_info);

       frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
       label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
           public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
             System.out.println("CLICKED");
             frame.setTitle("Mike");
           }
         });
       label1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
           public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
             System.out.println("CLICKED");
             frame.setTitle("Igal");
           }
         });
       while (i==0){
       //System.out.println("I am here");

       String s = frame.getTitle();
       System.out.println(s);
       if (s.equals("Mike")){
        i =1;
       }
       else if(s.equals("Igal")){
        i = 2;
       }
       // Add it to a frame.


    }
       System.out.println("im out");
       frame.setVisible(false);
       return i;

   }
```

Comment: Why not set the layout  contentPane.setLayout(null); https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: Don't use a null layout. Don't use setBounds(). Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. Then the layout manager will manage the size/location of components so that they look good on all platforms. Also, components should be added to the frame BEFORE the frame is made visible.

Comment: Swing and AWT methods and constructors need to be executed in the AWT event dispatch thread.  If they aren't, you get unpredictable behavior.  The fact that you're executing a `while` loop, and your application isn't hanging, suggests to me that you are not using the AWT event dispatch thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that your are calling `frame.setVisible(true)` before you are done making changes to `frame`. If you move this (and maybe the `pack()` call) pass all your `add()`s and after you `setContentFrame()`, then your window will open more reliably.

As for the alignment, that is going to come down to all your `setBounds()` calls. If you don't need to use `setBounds()` you should probably look into [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and nest `JPanel`s for modular sections of you're design (e.g. character info).

Comment: Actually `pack()` is worthless because you don't have a `LayoutManager` in your content frame. The use of `pack()` will only affect the default size of the window when it's not maximized,  so if you intend for this this it should moved, otherwise it should be removed.